# How does the filter option work?

Tags: websocket

If I want to use the WS-RPC to fetch tx's that have been made using a program. And if I only want tx's that are 50 bytes long then I send the WS server the following, right?

```
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            id: 1,
            method: 'programSubscribe',
            params: [
                'ADDRESS',
                {
                    encoding: 'base64',
                    commitment: 'finalized',
                    filters: [
                        {
                            dataSize: 50,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
```

Now my question is how can I determine the dataSize of a transaction? Is this the instruction data, accountKeys or is it the whole transaction in bytes?

Kind regards
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataSize` filter does not return "transactions" equal to the data size. It is used to returns accounts.

`getProgramAccounts` (or `programSubscribe` in case of websockets) method is used to fetch accounts only owned by a specific program. You can then use filters to get only specific accounts owned by the program.

The `dataSize` filter will return accounts that are exactly equal to the size in bytes you enter there. For example, token accounts are 165 bytes in size, so if you want to fetch all token accounts owned by a program, you would do:

```
  const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    program_id,
    {
      filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 165, // token account size
        },
      ],
    }
  );
```

You can then further use the `memcmp` filter to fetch accounts with specific field values.
Here's the full reference to [Get Program Account Filters](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#filters)

Note: I've used the word fetch here, but filtering is same in fetching via API request or getting updates via websockets, so not a thing to be confused about.

Answer (score 2):

The `programSubscribe` method will stream account changes and not transactions. In this case, the `dataSize` filter will filter accounts that match the given size.

In your case, you probably want to use the `logSubscribe` method in order to stream the signatures and logs of transactions involving a specific account/program.